# Power BI - How to add percentages to stacked column chart based on column total

Tags: powerbi, stackedbarseries

My data structure
[image: Data Structure]

I am trying to create a stacked column chart with percentages, but there is only option for percentage as grand total
[image: power BI visual]

I am looking for something like this, I dont want a 100% stacked chart

[image: needed visual]