# Power BI - How do I change the value from a decimal number to a percentage in a stacked column chart?

Tags: powerbi

I'm using two values in my stacked column chart and need the value to be a percentage as opposed to a decimal. I've transformed the data to a percentage but that is the extent of my Power BI knowledge base at this point.

Comment: Hi Tanya. You can find the answer here. Stay safe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68210045/power-bi-how-to-add-percentages-to-stacked-column-chart-based-on-column-total

Comment: Thanks but I don't see where the question was answered.